# Unable to connect Windows Azure to MySQL WorkBench

Tags: sql, azure

Hello guys,
              i am unable to connect mysql workbench with windows azure sql database so i can manage the DB from PC without issues.

Is their a way to do it.. ?  or is their an option or alternative to achieve my goal ?

Please help me regarding my query ! Thanks a lot :)

**UPDATE:**
Here is the error code i am getting:

[Window Title]
MySQL Workbench

[Main Instruction]
Cannot Connect to Database Server

[Content]
Your connection attempt failed for user 'username' from your host to server at xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net:1433:
  Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server xxxxxx.database.windows.net
2 Check that mysql is running on port 1433 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the username has rights to connect to xxxxxx.database.windows.net from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for xxxxxxx.database.windows.net connecting from the host address you're connecting from

[Close]

Comment: I'm not familiar with azure DB services. But if it is a simple VM in a cloud then you need to find out which port the DBMS is listening on, then create an 'Endpoint' for that port. After that you should be fine connecting to your_public_address:theport

Comment: its not in VM its normal db created just in azure.. And i tried with what details were provided in panel. the port and public URL and even added the IP to whitelist of the server..

Comment: doesn't Azure use SQL Server and not MySql?

Comment: i guess it do use sql server but i guess MySQL WorkBench is designed to support sql server and mysql both.

Answer (score 1):

Your server is xxxx.database.windows.net, so you are using SQL server, not MySQL server.

MySQL server format is: xxxx.mysql.database.azure.com.

You should use a MySQL server if you want to connect to MySQL Workbench.